# Python Dash: Update Layout from Outside of Callback-Function

Tags: python, user-interface, flask, request, plotly-dash

My goal is to run the Dash App on a laptop in a local network and trigger HTTP-requests from a microcontroller that resides in the same network. Those requests shall be catched by the Dash App and should update the layout of the App. So my goal ultimately is to implement some form of remote-control for the Dash App.

Catching HTTP-requests is no problem, when using a `Flask`-server and passing it to the `Dash`-object:

```py
import flask
import dash

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)

...

@server.route('/start_switch', methods=['GET'])
def start_switch():
    print('server.route ran!')
    
    # What do i run here to update layout-elements?

    return Response('', 200)

...
```

but since the main interactivity comes from dash-callbacks i don't know how i could update the layout as i would in:

```py
@app.callback(Output('show-status', 'children'),
              [Input('app2-status', 'children')])
def watch_kalibrierung(app2_status):
    """
    As soon as app2-status changes the function echoes
    its contents to the in div 'show-status'
    """
    return app2_status
```

because now, i'm not listening to a change in a UI-element but for the HTTP-Request.

I already tried writing a callback-function and calling it from the `@server.route`-function, but that didn't work.

How can i achieve my desired goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [dcc.Interval](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval) component to make the front end to poll changes for example every second. Then,

Something like

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


# Insert this component into your layout
# Every 1000 milliseconds, the n_interval is increased, which 
# can be tied to a callback
interval = dcc.Interval(
    id='interval-component',
    interval=1000, # in milliseconds
    n_intervals=0
)

# Tie a callback to the interval
@app.callback(Output('some-output-component', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_metrics(n):
    some_stuff = check_http_requests() # your custom function
    component = html.Div(some_stuff) # create new children for some-output-component
    return component
```

One simple way to pass data from the HTTP requests to the `check_http_requests()` would be to use queues ([queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/queue.html)) into which you would put the HTTP requests. Now, how this should be implemented depends on your needs. If you need be able to serve multiple users at same time, you have to make a logic so that each user would have their own queues which should be checked.